Filippov Solutions and Infinitesimal Zeno Behavior
I just learned about Filippov solutions; they're really amazing. However, I still am having a little trouble wrapping my head about something.
I'll provide an example below, then pose my question.
Example.
Suppose that time is continuous ($t\in [0,\infty)$) and that $x_t\in[0,\infty)$ has initial condition $x_0\in[0,\infty)$. Further suppose that it satisfies the (autonomous) ODE,  $\dot{x}_t =\begin{cases}\ \ \  0, & \text{if } x_t=0 \\ -1, & \text{if } x_t>0  \end{cases}$, where $\dot{x}_t$ denotes the time derivative of $x_t$.
Conjecture. It seems that $\bar{x}=0$ is a Filippov solution of this ODE (I am not sure how to formally show this; this is purely based on intuition and my [possibly incorrect] understanding of the definition of Filippov solutions). Intuitively $x_t$ drifts downwards until it reaches $0$ at some time $t=\tau\geq0$; it then proceeds to forever oscillate by an arbitrarily small amount (formally, this seems to be a certain type of "Zeno behavior.")
My main question. If my conjecture is correct, I understand that the aforementioned behavior is probably considered pathalogical at least in some sense. However, I am wondering if it is "very pathological" in the sense that it would be correct for you to respond with something along the lines of the following:

"your intuition is correct, but since $x_t$ is so ill-behaved after it reaches $0$, you actually can't say that $0$ is stable in any sense because $\underline{\qquad}$ is fundamentally ill-defined and/or necessarily leads to a contradiction.''

Another (not main) question. Any advice/references on how to show something is (or isn't) a Fillipov solution would be appreciated.
